# Rails6 resize uploaded images with Action Text & Active Storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I've upgraded my project to Rails 6 and now using Action Text in my model "Article".

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_rich_text :content
end
```

However in my project most of uploaded images are too big to store, so I want to resize them before saving.

How should I resize attached images and replace them in "trix-file-accept" listener?

```
// app/javascript/trix-editor-overrides.js
window.addEventListener("trix-file-accept", function (event) {
 // ...
})
```

Comment: Here is an article on resizing images through JS on the client-side: https://zocada.com/compress-resize-images-javascript-browser/

Comment: @bo-oz thank you very much, I'll check!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To store images you can listen for the `trix-attachment-add` event. You can attached images with XMLHttpRequest by yourself through custom controller and there If you want resize attachment before save, try use e.g [minimagic](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick). Check [trix editor](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#storing-attached-files) page. Instead, If you just need to display resized attachment Active Storage will lazily transform the original blob into the specified format. Located under `app/views/active_storage/blobs/`, this partial is auto created by Rails when were run the `rails action_text:install` script. This gets called for every attachment that is part of the Action Text and there you can resize image:

```
  <!--app/views/active_storage/blobs/_blob.html.erb-->
  <% if blob.representable? %>
    <%= image_tag blob.representation(resize_to_limit:local_assigns[:in_gallery] ? [ 800, 600 ] :[1024, 768 ]) %>
  <% end %>
```

More info here

[Handling attachments in Action Text in Rails 6](https://blog.saeloun.com/2019/11/12/attachments-in-action-text-rails-6.html)

[Active Storage Transforming Images](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images)